# Converting input containing special character to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the beginning of my program that calculates simple interest. Interest rate will have the following format : 0.97 , 0.67 , 0.17 etc. They won't be bigger than 1. So if the user enter 9 for the interest, program will convert it to 0.09 (by dividing it by 100) . Also user can enter input using '/'. So program will convert input like 97/100 to 0.97.

I wrote the code below. It works but it seems to me that there might be a easier and more elegant solution to this. Maybe using more build-in functions etc. If you help me with that I would be very appreciated.

```
def toNum(interest):

    if '/' not in interest:
        if float(interest) > 1:
            return float(interest)/100

        else:
            return float(interest)


    else:
        l= []
        n = 0
        count = 1

        list_interest=[]
        for e in interest:
            list_interest.append(e)

        for e in list_interest:

            if count == 1 or count == 3:
                l.append(e)
                count = count +1
                continue


            if e == '/':
                n = n + 1
                count = count +1
            else:
                l[n] = l[n] + e

        return int(l[0]) / int(l[1])









interest = input("Interest rate: ")
interest = toNum(interest)
print(interest)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reading a fraction such as "97/100", you can use the `fractions` library.

For example:

```python
from fractions import Fraction

f = Fraction("97/100")

print(float(f)) # prints 0.97
```

And because the constructor also takes a float, we can remove the check for `/`. Therefore, the final code is:

```python
from fractions import Fraction

def toNum(interest):
    f = Fraction(interest)
    f = float(f)

    if f > 1:
        f /= 100

    return f

print(toNum("97/100")) # prints 0.97
print(toNum(0.97)) # prints 0.97
print(toNum(9)) # prints 0.09
```

Comment: Why convert to `float` at all and not keep a `fractions.Fraction` object all along?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger That's also a good option, just depends on preference.

Answer (score 1):

While the [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/208449/98493) by [@esote](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/118395/esote) is correct and I would also recommend using the `fractions` module, you should also work on your text parsing. In this case you could have used a simple [`str.split`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split) and [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) to parse the string containing a `/`:

```
if "/" in interest:
    numerator, denominator = map(int, interest.split("/"))
    return numerator / denominator
```

Note that `int` ignores whitespace, so this works with both `"97/100"`, `"97 / 100"` and any combination thereof.

Note also that using sensible names makes it immediately obvious what this code does.